# Copy Constructor for a String Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, constructor, interface, copy-constructor

So I'm currently working on a project that is recreating methods for Array String Lists and Linked String Lists. There is a StringList interface, that both ArrayStringList and LinkedStringList implement. We are not allowed to see the source code for the interface - only the API documentation. For each class, we have to create a default constructor and copy constructor for both classes. I've ran tests, and the default constructors both pass but the ArrayStringList copy constructor does not work and has been throwing the error message of "null" or "-1". I am pretty new to inheritance and interfaces, and I think the object parameters vs string array data types are throwing me off a bit.

Here is the code I have so far, and the methods used in the constructor:

**My Copy Constructor:**

```
private String[] stringArray;
private int size;

public ArrayStringList(StringList sl) {
    size = sl.size();
    ArrayStringList asl = new ArrayStringList();
    for(int i = 0; i < size-1; i++) {
        if(sl.get(i) != null) {
            asl.set(i,sl.get(i).toString());
        } //if
    } // for
} // copy constructor
```

**Size Method:**

```
public int size() {
    return stringArray.length;
} // size
```

**Get Method:**

```
public String get(int index) {
    if(index < 0 || index >= size) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("out of bounds");
} else {
        return stringArray[index];
    }
} //get
```

**Set Method:**

```
public String set(int index, String s) {
    String old = stringArray[index];
stringArray[index] = s;
    return old;
} // set
```

In the project, the description of the copy constructor was as follows:

*The implementing class must explicitly define a copy constructor. The copy constructor should take exactly one parameter of the interface type StringList. It should make the newly constructed list object a deep copy of the list referred to by the constructor's parameter. Therefore, the initial size and string elements of the new list object will be the same as the other list. To be clear, the other list can be an object of any implementation of the StringList interface. No other assumptions about the type of the object should be made.*

Comment: if(sl.get(i) != null)  why are you checking null here?

Comment: post documentation of set method

Comment: can you define ArrayStringList<String> asl = new ArrayStringList<>(); like this ?

Comment: please, provide the `Interface` you are trying to implement

Comment: @SSP - I've added the set. And I just tried adding that in to try to get rid of the null error and see where exactly it was occurring.

Comment: @SSP I unfortunately cannot define it that way :( We have to do it manually using a string array. I believe the ArrayStringList<String> already has all those methods

Comment: @RostyslavBarmakov I am unable to see the source code, but the API documentation is here: http://cobweb.cs.uga.edu/~mec/cs1302/listadt-api/cs1302/listadt/StringList.html

Comment: did you write set method?

Comment: Its wrong and returning null.

Comment: @SSP yes i wrote all the methods above - the only thing I can't change is the signatures. In the API documentation it says "return: the string previously at the specified position." do I need to call a .toString() on the array first?

Comment: ArrayStringList  what are method present in this class for adding or setting data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class ArrayStringList implements StringList {

  private static final int INITIAL_CAPACITY = 10;

  private String[] stringArray;
  private int size;

  public ArrayStringList(StringList sl) {
    stringArray = sl.toArray();
    size = stringArray.length;
  }


  public ArrayStringList() {
    stringArray = new String[INITIAL_CAPACITY];
    size = 0;
  }

  // TODO: Extract 'if-cascade' to an validate(..) method 
  @Override
  public String set(int index, String s) {
    if (index >= size) {
      throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("")
    } else if (s == null) {
      throw new NullPointerException("the specified string is null");
    } else if (s.isEmpty()) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("specified string is empty");
    }
    String old = stringArray[index];
    stringArray[index] = s;
    return old;
  }

  // TODO: Check if posible to extend the stringArray
  @Override
  public boolean add(String s) {
    if (s == null) {
      throw new NullPointerException("the specified string is null");
    } else if (s.isEmpty()) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("specified string is empty");
    }

    if (size == stringArray.length) {
      int newListCapacity = stringArray.length * 2;
      stringArray = Arrays.copyOf(stringArray, newListCapacity);
    }
    stringArray[++size] = s;
    return true;
  }

  // TODO: implement other methods ...
}
```

Keep in mind that this implementation is still buggy, but you can use it as a starting point

Comment: You are welcome! PS: I've just updated the default constructor and `add(..)` method

Answer (score 1):

I would initialise the internal array to the value of `size` and also make use of the fact that the `String` class also has a copy-constructor

```
public ArrayStringList(StringList sl) {
    this.size = sl.size();
    this.stringArray = new String[size];
    for(int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        this.stringArray[j] = new String(sl.get(i));
    } 
}
```

Comment: This is so helpful, thank you! It doesn't seem to compile on that last line, with String(sl.get(i)); and says it cannot find the symbol. Would I use StringList instead?

Comment: It does compile when I take out the String all together. Would that still work the same? When I run a test without the String, it still throws the -1 error.

Comment: @FrancesBrown The `-1` error might be related to your iteration, which stops at `i < size-1` - in case you did not copy the code from this answer.

Comment: Your `String(sl.get(i))` is not valid Java. Additionally, the String class in Java is immutable and does not need to be copied.

Comment: @FrancesBrown sorry I missed the `new` keyword

Answer (score 1):

```
public void ArrayStringList(StringList sl) {
    size = sl.size();
    ArrayStringList asl = new ArrayStringList();
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if(sl.get(i) != null) {
            String s  = asl.set(i,sl.get(i).toString());
            System.out.println(s);
        } //if
    } // for
}
```

Change set method like below. And call it by the help of class object. it will set value in global static list.

```
//Change set method like this
public String set(int index, String s) {

    stringArray[index] = s;
    return stringArray[index];
}
```